# What does it mean to place a "piece of parchment paper and an inverted lid of foil" to cover

Tags: braising

I'm working with a dutch oven, and i'm braising short ribs. I'm assuming the idea to place  a "piece of parchment paper and an inverted lid of foil" to cover means to seal the pot further so no liquid evaporates in the process.

But I'm not sure how to seal it by that statement. Does it mean the aluminum foil covers the pot, then place parchment paper on top, then close it with the lid?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe cut the paper in a circle and put directly over the meat in the pot.

After that you put the foil over the pot and then the lid ?

this:

http://www.seriouseats.com/2016/04/how-to-make-a-parchment-paper-lid.html

and this:

http://www.thekitchn.com/culinary-school-tip-braise-wit-43041